# SQLAlchemy - Filter query, exclude parent where one of many children meet criteria

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

My SQL skills are pretty lacking, so I can't figure out how to form the query I need.

I've got two db models with a one to many relationship, defined like this:

```
class Parent(db.Model):
  __tablename__ = 'parent'

  id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)

  children = db.relationship('Child', 
                             backref = 'parent', 
                             lazy = 'joined')

class Child(db.Model):
  __tablename__ = 'child'

  id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
  parent_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('parent.id'))

  value = db.Column(db.String(140))
```

I'd like to be able to form a query that will return all the parents that meet three conditions:

1: have one or more children whose value contains 'value1'

2: have one or more children whose value contains 'value2'

3: have no children whose value contains 'value3' or 'value4'

For this example data:

```
Parents:
id |
1  |
2  |
3  |
4  |

Children:
id | parent_id | value
1  | 1         | 'value1'
2  | 1         | 'value2'
3  | 1         | 'value3'
4  | 1         | 'value5'

5  | 2         | 'value1'
6  | 2         | 'value2'
7  | 2         | 'value4'
8  | 2         | 'value5'

9  | 3         | 'value1'
10 | 3         | 'value2'
11 | 3         | 'value5'
12 | 3         | 'value6'

13 | 4         | 'value1'
14 | 4         | 'value7'
```

I'd want only Parent #3 to be returned.

This is as far as I've gotten:

```
from sqlalchemy import not_, and_

conditions = []

conditions.append(Parent.children.any(Child.value.ilike('%'+value1+'%'))
conditions.append(Parent.children.any(Child.value.ilike('%'+value2+'%'))

conditions.append(Parent.children.any(not_(Child.value.ilike('%'+value3+'%')))

condition = and_(*conditions)

q = db.session.query(Parent).filter(condition)
```

This first two conditions work fine. Setting the relationship to lazy='join' allows me to call .any() on the relationship, and get the results I'm after.

Condtion 3, however, isn't working as it is. It's returning Parents who have a single child that doesn't meet the criteria, rather than having ALL children not meet the criteria.

I've messed around with outer joins and other ways of performing this query, but I've realized I don't know enough about SQL to figure out which direction to head. Can anyone point me in the right direction? Just knowing the SQL I need to generate would be a big step in the right direction, but getting it working in SQLAlchemy would be awesome.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Query below should do it:

```
q = (session.query(Parent)
     .filter(Parent.children.any(Child.value.ilike('%{}%'.format(value1))))
     .filter(Parent.children.any(Child.value.ilike('%{}%'.format(value2))))
     .filter(~Parent.children.any(
         db.or_(Child.value.ilike('%{}%'.format(value3)),
                Child.value.ilike('%{}%'.format(value4)),
                )
     ))
)
```

Few points:

- you need an `or` for Condition-3
- you also should use `NOT has any children...` (which is done using `~`) instead or the `not` which you have inside.

Filter for Condition-3 should be: *Parents which DO NOT HAVE ANY children that DOES satisfy bla-bla*, whereas your code implies *Parents which HAVE AT LEAST ONE child that DOES NOT satisfy bla-bla*.

Comment: Thanks, that worked great. It seems obvious now, but I just couldn't get my head around that.